# Get row data based of onclick event react, using html tables in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

newbie to react I was previously using ParentNode in my previous non react project to get values that were on the same row as the button the triggered the onclick, so here is the problem

This the table rendered below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q990A.png)

So the problem I am experiencing is I am unable to access the value right of the delete question button, what is the best way to do this?

The component that renders that table

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { currentloginid } from '../login/loginid.js';
import { deletequestion } from '../question/deletequestion.js';

// App component just as an example
export const ViewQuestionComponent = () => {
  let [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const handleViewQuestion = async () => {
    try {      
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=viewquestion', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      const result = await data;
      // const id = await currentloginid(); // I didn't see where you use this id
      setState(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ViewQuestion onClick={handleViewQuestion} />
      <div id="questions">
        <Table rows={state}>
          <DeleteButton onClick={deletequestion} />
        </Table>
      </div>
   </div>
  );
};

export function ViewQuestion({onClick}) {
    return (
        <Button onClick={onClick}>View Question</Button>
    );
}

export default ViewQuestion;

const Table = ({rows, children}) => (
  <table className="ui single line table">
    <tbody>
     { rows.map(row =>
       <tr key={row.questionid}>
        <td>{row.question}</td>
        <td>{row.timestamp}</td>
        <td>{row.catagories}</td>
        <td>{(row.answer === null ? "Not Answered" : row.answer)}</td>
        <td>{children}</td>
        <td>{row.questionid}</td>
       </tr>
      )}
   </tbody>
  </table>
);

const DeleteButton = ({onClick}) => (
  <button className="ui negative basic button" onClick={onClick.bind(this)}>Delete Question</button>
);
```

The function that gets triggered when the button is pressed

```
export function deletequestion(row) {
    console.log("Hi");
    var questionid = row;
    console.log(questionid);
    fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=deletequestion', 
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        }
        )
}
```

What is the best way to get the questionid value. A detailed explanation would be great, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> So the problem I am experiencing is I am unable to access the value right of the delete question button, what is the best way to do this?

The best practice is to get the value from React state. This contrasts how you'd do this in jQuery (or other imperative frameworks).

In jQuery it's common to write the info to the DOM and then pull relative information via querying for another element relative to where an event target is. E.g. as you describe:

> I was previously using ParentNode in my previous non react project to get values that were on the same row as the button the triggered the onclick

In React, the model is very different. Instead of relying on the DOM as your source of truth, you rely on React state (e.g. from `useState`) as the source of truth and the resulting DOM is thought of as a function of your state (vs being the source of truth itself).

This is better because your data is decoupled from the resulting DOM and changes to your design don't result in you having to update your code to pull from the correct relative node.

---

To finally answer your question, assuming your state is an array of items, I would pass the `questionid` to the `deletequestion` function when you map over the array.

I would also change the composition of your components so that `DeleteButton` is inside your `Table` component. This brings the row state into the same place where you're rendering the delete button.

Finally, I would also inline the `DeleteButton` component into `Table` vs having it as a separate component. This removes an unneeded abstraction layer and makes the data in the `row` object more accessible.

```js
// note, you would import this instead of relying on a global
// this is just for stack overflow
const { render } = ReactDOM;

function deletequestion(questionid) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  searchParams.append('action', 'deletequestion');
  searchParams.append('questionid', questionid);
  
  alert(`clicked delete question with id ${questionid}`);
}

const Table = ({ rows }) => (
  <table className="ui single line table">
    <tbody>
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <tr key={row.questionid}>
          <td>{row.question}</td>
          <td>{row.timestamp}</td>
          <td>{row.catagories}</td>
          <td>{row.answer === null ? 'Not Answered' : row.answer}</td>
          <td>{row.questionid}</td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="ui negative basic button"
              //                   pass it here!   
              onClick={() => deletequestion(row.questionid)}
              //                                   
            >
              Delete Question
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);


// the code below is just for the example, don't actually copy it
const rows = [
  { question: 'question 1', timestamp: new Date().toLocaleString(), categories: 'cat 1', answer: null, questionid: 1 },
  { question: 'question 2', timestamp: new Date().toLocaleString(), categories: 'cat 2', answer: null, questionid: 2 },
];

const container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

render(<Table rows={rows} />, container);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok thanks, the code isn't working I'm getting ```SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: MouseEvent, target: button.ui.negative.basic.button, …}``` but I should be expecting a number instead

Comment: The code does work. I updated it so it's runnable inside of stackoverflow. Make sure you're passing in the correct event handler function e.g. `() => deletequestion(row.questionid)`